# "VBA autofilter method of range class failed" error on a code that worked earlier today

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA code that deletes all the rows with the value "No" in column W, then sorts it. Right now I keep getting the

> VBA autofilter method of range class failed

error on the `.AutoFilter 1, "*No*"` line. The strange thing is, this worked earlier today and I tested it multiple times, but then it suddenly stopped working.

What should I do to get rid of this error?

```
Sub FilterMacro()

Dim Lastrow As Long

  'Delete
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduction - Filtered")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("W1", Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "*No*"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Lastrow = Worksheets("Deduction - Filtered").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduction - Filtered").Range("L2").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduction - Filtered").Range("L2:L" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H2, H2)>1, (L1-Q1), K2)"

 'Sort
Columns("H:H").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduction - Filtered").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduction - Filtered").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "H2:H" & Lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduction - Filtered").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:AB" & Lastrow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: First of all get rid of all lines with `.Select` statement - they're useless. Second - comment the line `On Error Resume Next` (in order to disable this line). Third - debug your sub line by line and find out which of them throws an error - go to your module, left-click anywhere between lines `Sub FilterMacro()` and `End Sub`, then press F8 to step into sub and keep pressing F8 until the error is thrown, then edit your post, add info about this line and a sample of worksheet that generates this error.

Comment: Ah. I mentioned above but it's the ".AutoFilter 1, "No" " line that gives me this error. Furthermore it worked earlier today but stopped working. :(

Comment: Well then, the most obvious reason for that error - is that the filtered column doesn't have the criteria value. I mean that you're trying to sort it with "No" criteria, but there are no "No" 's values in it. If you have now the example that works - replace manually all "No" values with anything else and try again.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to activate the worksheet. Now it works fine XD

Comment: That's a bad thing to use `Activate` or `Select` when you actually don't need to activate or select something. It always may trick you like now. VBA gives you an opportunity and tools to deal with almost everything without selecting/activating it. Check out my reply to this post, 'cos comment has a limit. If it helps - mark as answer, if there are questions - post a comment and I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in my comment

> most obvious reason for that error - is that the filtered column
>   doesn't have the criteria value. I mean that you're trying to sort it
>   with "No" criteria, but there are no "No" 's values in it.

And as you've confirmed

> I figured it out. I had to activate the worksheet. Now it works fine
>   XD

Don't use `Activesmth`, use named variables instead (I may be mistaken in terminology). Here's your code refactored to 11 lines (if don't count comments) and without using autofilter.

```
Sub FilterMacro()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sortRange As Range
Dim rowNo As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deduction - Filtered")   ' define the "permanent" address to the sheet you're working with
                                                        ' ThisWorkbook - is the wb where the code is placed (in it's module)
                                                        ' ActiveWorkbook - is the file which is active at this time, and it may be different files
                                                        ' that means that if you launch the code marked as ActiveWorkbook from one wb, and then
                                                        ' accidentally switch to other - the running code will assume that wb as an ActiveWorkbook.
                                                        ' If you use ThisWorkbook - code will always try to refer to wb from wich it is launched,
                                                        ' otherwise it will throw an exception.

    ' Delete:
    ' rows where there is no "No" in column W
With sht
    For rowNo = .Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(rowNo, 23) = "No" Then .Cells(rowNo, 23).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

    ' Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 28).End(xlUp)) is equivalent of Range("A1:AB" & Lastrow(from your code)) but a bit simpler
    '//////I don't know the exact sort range, so check this thing, it was taken from original post \\\\\\
Set sortRange = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 28).End(xlUp))
End With

    ' Sort:
    ' Here you may click on the "Sort" word and press F1 to load help and see other parameters
    ' I used ones you posted (maybe except order1)
    ' check this stuff as well
sortRange.Sort key1:=sortRange, _
                order1:=xlAscending, _
                Header:=xlYes, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                SortMethod:=xlPinYin

End Sub
```

And an advise - never use autofilter to edit data with vba, use it only to show something